# Class extended from Zend_View_Abstract does not adher to setNoRender()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've copied a class 'class Ext_View_Smarty extends Zend_View_Abstract' from [gediminasm.org](http://gediminasm.org/post/smarty-3-extension-for-zend-framework)

The problem occurs when I try to use Soap calls.

I did the following:

```
class SoapController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function init()
  {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
  }
```

But this will still try to show the layout.tpl file.

What can I change in the Ext_View_Smarty class so that the render function will simply not be called?
Obviously I still want it to be called in case of an error. Then it should still open up the error.tpl file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

To SoapController...